Powershell : Im failing to get directories+files in a particular path using get-ChildItem cmdlet
I have a path where there are many directories with files and files outside the directory.
I want to extract all files/directories maintaining the folder structure.
Please help if possible.
Thank you in advance.
Command used :
$Path = "Some path"

$Binaries = Get-ChildItem -Directory -File -Path $Path -Recurse
Write-Host $Binaries

Output : empty

Can you see the files using Windows File Explorer?  You may not have permission in PS.  Try starting PS by right click on PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Using both switches -Directory and -File is wrong. Use just -File and -Force

If I understood your last comment correctly you are aiming to create one zip archive of an folder and its full content via powershell command.
I would download 7zip and use the following command for convenience:
Compress-Archive -Path c:\msi -DestinationPath c:\logs\test.zip -CompressionLevel Optimal



To get a list of directories, use the -Directory parameter (limit the result to directories only).
To get a list of files, use the -File parameter (limit the result to files only).

To fetch all files and folders together, omit both parameters -Directory and -File as those are mutually exclusive: Get-ChildItem -File -Directory returns $null…
Example:
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse).Count -eq (
       (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse).Count +
       (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse).Count)   # True

$null -eq (Get-ChildItem -File -Directory)          # True
$null -eq (Get-ChildItem -File -Directory -Recurse) # True


I am fetching all the files by using -File -Recurse. Also I want to create a zip maintaining the folder structure.
